# Build size has increased after including alibaba short video sdk

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I used alibaba short video editing pod. Due which build size has increased more than 30 MB.
How can I reduce build size.
Below is the pods used.

````
  pod 'AlivcCore', :path => 'AlivcCore/'
  pod 'AlivcRecord', :path => 'AlivcRecord/'
  pod 'AlivcEdit', :path => 'AlivcEdit/'```
````

Comment: Check this document https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/95794.htm maybe it will work for you

Comment: Hi, I followed he document. Document has old version reference.
Please check below versions.
  ```pod 'VODUpload', :git => 'https://github.com/aliyunvideo/VODUpload.git',:tag => '1.5.3'
  pod 'QuCore-ThirdParty',:git => 'https://github.com/aliyunvideo/QuCore-ThirdParty.git',:tag => '3.15.0'
  pod 'AliyunVideoSDKPro',:git => 'https://github.com/aliyunvideo/AliyunVideoSDKPro.git',:tag => '3.16.1'
  pod 'AlivcConan',:git => 'https://github.com/aliyunvideo/AlivcConanSDK.git',:tag => '1.0.3'
  pod 'AliyunRace',:git => 'https://github.com/aliyunvideo/AliyunRace.git',:tag => '1.2.0'```

Comment: Also, I see AliyunVideoSDKPro.git is contributing more build size.